sorting a stack with the help of other 2 temp stack
Need a help on sorting stack. Need to sort a stack of integer with the help of other 2 temp stacks, but the condition is in any point of time, we can not put bigger integer on top of small integer.
Without the condition I can solve, but not able do it with the condition.

Without the condition, the fastest stack sort using 2 temp stacks is a polyphase merge sort as shown in this answer .

That is Tower of Hanoi. Just look for that and you will find a lot of solutions.
